# Object is not a value error in scala

Tags: scala, object, dictionary

While trying to make a map in Scala, I receive the following error message: *object Map is not a value*

The code I'm using is the following:

```
val myStringMap =  Map[String, String]("first" -> "A", "second" -> "B", "third" -> "C")
```

I am quite puzzled as to why I cannot create this map because after looking at Scala documentation, it seems to me that the syntax of my code is proper.

Comment: If I start up a REPL and paste in this code, it works fine; that it doesn't for you suggests something about the rest of your setup. What version of Scala are you running against, what imports do you have etc. Something in the context is likely hiding the standard import of `Map` and causing this problem.

Comment: Which scala version? Works for me in the REPL: `myStringMap: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(first -> A, second -> B, third -> C)` in 2.9.0.1

Comment: Many thanks for the quick response. I discovered that I was importing java.utils.map without actually using it. Removing the import also removed my error.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

When you see the error "object is not a value" this typically means that the in-scope type is a Java type - you probably are importing `java.util.Map` in scope

```
scala> Map(1 -> "one")
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,java.lang.String] = Map(1 -> one)
```

But

```
scala> import java.util.Map
import java.util.Map

scala> Map(1 -> "one")
<console>:9: error: object Map is not a value
              Map(1 -> "one")
              ^
```

Remember, in scala each *class* comes with a (optional) **companion object** which is a value. This is not true of Java classes.

Comment: Say I'm not shadowing a builtin class but trying to use a Java Class. What should I do to get that *companion object*?.

Comment: I don't understand solution. So, how to fix it? :)

Answer (score 6):

Because in scala each native scala class comes with an (optional) companion object (allowing for assignment from the companion object as in your example code) when incorporating a java class into scala code always remember to instantiate the class by invoking the constructor, ie. use keyword "new", thus creating a value.

Answer (score 3):

Just found this so maybe it will be useful to share my solution. 
If you have imported java.util.Map and need to use scala.collection.immutable.Map then use it with the full name so instead of

```
 Map(1 -> "one")
```

do

```
scala.collection.immutable.Map(1 -> "one")
```

This way it will know what you mean

Answer (score 1):

I got similar error on Lists. try this in scala console:

```
import java.util.List

object test {
   def a():List[String] = {   
      val list = List[String]();    
      null  
   }
}
```

you'll get the err `"Object List is not a value."`

You get it because you're hiding the built-in List type, that is because List is different from `java.util.List`

What if someone wants to use util.List?

you can use a qualified name or a rename import

```
! import java.util.{List => JList}

import java.util.{List=>JList}
```

Comment: This doesn't wok for me