# Using Java locale in Scala complains: object is not a value

Tags: java, scala, locale

I'm trying to use a java locale in Scala. Using a constant like `java.util.Locale.ENGLISH` works well; however, `java.util.Locale("en")` complains:

```
error: object Locale is not a value
java.util.Locale("en")`
```

This seems related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9079129/object-is-not-a-value-error-in-scala), which suggests Locale doesn't have a companion object. I've been [reading a bit about this](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/scala/singleton-and-companion-objects.html), but I still can't figure out how one is to access the Locale **class**?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do not forget to instantiate locale with **new** keyword, since it's class:

```
scala> new java.util.Locale("en")
res0: java.util.Locale = en
```

Comment: And here I was, complicating simple things... thanks for the pointer!