# Package list is not a value in Scala Eclipse

Tags: list, scala

I have followed the course of "Functional Programming in Scala" on coursera. In week5 List, lecture5.2, when trying to construct a List, I get the error of "Package list is not a value ", the code is as folowing

```
package week5

object Test extends App{

 def msort(x:List[Int]):List[Int] = {
     val mid = x.length/2
     if (mid == 0) x
     else{
       def merge(x:List[Int],y:List[Int]):List[Int] = (x, y) match {
         case (Nil,y) =>y
         case (x,Nil) =>x
         case (x1::xs1, y1::ys1) =>{
            if(x1 < y1) x1 :: merge(xs1,y)
            else y1 :: merge(x, ys1)
         }
       }
      val (fst,snd) = x.splitAt(mid)
      val sfst = msort(fst)
      val ssnd = msort(snd)
      merge(sfst,ssnd)
    }
  }

  val x = List(-4,2,5,-10,9,8,5)   //error, Package list is not a value
  val sx = msort(x)
}
```

Does anybody know the problem?

the error message is:Package list is not a value as following image[image: error]

Comment: can you paste the exact error message?

Comment: the error message is:Package list is not a value as the above picture

Answer (score 0):

I copy your code to my IDE(intellij), it works well. 
[image]

Comment: I have copied into scala console in the terminal, it works as well. I wonder if I need to import some scala package which includes List in eclipse? Or do I need to change the JVM?

Comment: @Johnson I do not think there is need to change the JVM. Have you compiled it in eclipse? maybe it can be complied when the IDE shows some errors.

Comment: according to [Object is not a value error in scala] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9079129/object-is-not-a-value-error-in-scala"), this is probably cause by importing of java library. I have fixed it by using "scala.collection.immutable.List(-4,2,5,-10,9,8,5)" instead of "List(-4,2,5,-10,9,8,5)".   But the question is I don't see any importing of java list in my code. Does it has something to do with Scala JVM?

Comment: I think the error may be caused by the configuration in your ide, which results in the mess of 'List' . You can check it.